# USB device listening OSX objective c using peertalk

Tags: objective-c, macos, usb, appstore-sandbox

I developed a OSX application that listening the USB devices that connected from OSX and application runs fine before submit to app store. At the time of submission to app store I enabled the "App Sandbox" and enabled USB in App Sandbox. But after enable this application is not able to get the list of USB connected devices. I am using peertalk library from github. Link is below:

[PeerTalk](https://github.com/rsms/peertalk)

So now please can anyone suggest the solution for this. or suggest any option to get the devices list which is connected from osx using USB.

Thanks
Mit

Comment: could you post  your entitlements.plist?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.device.usb</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
 <string>/var/run/usbmuxd</string>
</dict>
</plist>